# From 1 to 5-shot learning with data augmentation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision, data-augmentation

I'm currently exploring k-shot classification and I would like to start a first experiment on logo classification.

The problem is that for some logos I can only find one image, while for others I found 5 different ones. Do you think I can augment the class containing only one image to make 5 different images ? Would it hurt the model performance ? Am I better off doing a 1-shot classification instead ?